# Кто поможет с написанием программы?

Tags: c++

Не знаю как написать с базой в с++

Задача программы: вычислить стоимость покупки. Входные данные: перечень товаров, их количество наличие скидок.

Необходимо создать базу данных для 50 товаров, указав номер, название и стоимость.

Кассир задает товар по номеру, а также количество товара (штук или кг).

Задавая номер, программа добавляет товар в корзину и считает общую стоимость.

Программа осложнена следующим:

1.На категорию отдельных товаров (10 товаров из списка) начисляется скидка после 20 часов в размере 15% от стоимости.

2. Если покупка на сумму более 300 грн, то начисляется скидка 10%.
3. При покупке 3 товаров, третий товар является бесплатным (бесплатным тот, что самый дешевый).

4.В каждом чеке после стоимости выводится афоризм (если стоимость в чеке до 50 грн один афоризм, 50-100 грн второй, 100-150 грн третий и т.д.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратитесь, например, [сюда](http://www.reshaem.net/?cGFydG5lcj03OTIy). Здесь - не тот сайт, где делают работу за других.

Answer (score 1):

@Magistr для начала необходимо понять в какой ОС вы работаете. 
Предположу, что windows. 
Затем Вам необходимо выбрать программу для работы с кодом C++. Их много разных.

Одна из популярных для windows - гайд по созданию программы на С++ -  Visual Studio от microsoft. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-a-standard-cpp-program-cpp?view=vs-2019
Затем Вам необходимо создать базу данных - https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer?view=vs-2019
После того, как Вы всё это сделаете и создадите базу, настройте подключение к ней и попробуйте написать код.

Если у Вас возникнут проблемы уже с написанием кода - смело создавайте вопрос на данном сайте. Вам обязательно помогут.

К сожалению, делать за Вас работу с нуля никто не будет. Вы как минимум должны сами попробовать это сделать. На то и существуют задания.